# Exhaust Manifold Nuts won't screw in all the way

Tags: exhaust, rust, stuck-bolt

after installing the new headers on my car I am having an issue with the bolts not going in all the way in both from the cat end and the block end and I am afraid of snapping them from using too much force. The thing is they came out very easily without even having to use penetrating fluid but now they are giving me troubles going in, why is that happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Are you talking about nuts, bolts or studs?  Are you sure you haven't cross-threaded something?  What happens if you loosen everything up and try tightening each fastener a little bit in a star pattern?

Comment: If these are bolts, are you sure the holes you're putting them into are clean of debris *and* fluids? Are you sure you're using the correct fasteners? If you got them mixed up (say a coarse thread bolt for the fine thread bolt of the same thickness bolt), it would start in the hole, but not tighten down correctly. Just spitballing.

Comment: I am talking about the nuts. Would cross-threading make the nut not go all the way in even if there is still space on the stud?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I am using the same nuts that were on the old one

Comment: Are the flanges on the new headers thinner than the old manifolds?  Also, can you post a pic?

Comment: I will once I get back home but no they aren't. The issue isn't even with the header, the nut still has a lot of clearance but still won't go in. I believe I would have the same issue if there was no header at all installed

Comment: If one of the nuts was crossthreaded previously and you have mixed them up it will be either crossthreading another stud or recutting itself on the new thread. Id take all the nuts out and run a tap through them all. They should feel the same. Id also run the matching die over each stud and try again.

Comment: Your use of English is not making this clear - " nut not go all the way in".  Nuts don't go in anything, they go 'on' or 'down' a thread, but not 'in'.  Are you able to describe it better?  You might be better putting the old nuts in the trash and get some new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the issue was that I mixed the bolts that connected the exhaust manifold to the catalytic convert with the bolts the connected the manifold with the block. apparently they are different despite looking identical and thus they wouldn't screw in all the way. Thank you every one

Comment: Thanks for getting back with a resolution. I was curious to see what the issue was

Answer (score 1):

You say it is nuts going down on studs?    Probably because the flange on the new headers is thinner than the flange on the originals.  So the nut is having to run down farther down the stud.   Essentially entering a zone where "no nut has gone before" which is thick with gunk or rust.

Run a thread-chaser or tap down each of the studs, should clean that up.

Comment: Yes but they are not even going half way in, like I said in a comment even if the header wasn't there the nut wouldn't screw in. It is very hard for some odd reason